can I replace only caliper pistons or just replace the whole caliper?

my front right wheel is getting hot after driving 30kms
it has a history of collision on the front right side (previous owner)
I've already tried rebuilding using some caliper repair kit but issue is still the same
my next item to check is the caliper or caliper piston

now, should I first replace the caliper pistons for now? or just replace the whole brake caliper?
replacing the whole caliper is a bit expensive that's why I just wanted to check first if the caliper piston replacement will fix it. but would it be better to just replace the caliper?

Are the brake pads in that calliper evenly worn, or is one pad much thinner than the other?

thanks. that one, I haven't checked but I will.

I presume you have checked that the heat is down to the brakes dragging and not another cause? Especially given the history of accident damage. Does the wheel spin freely with the caliper removed, without any rumbling, tight spots, etc? Is all the alignment correct?
The next things I'd check are the sliders (the pins that allow the caliper to slide) and the flexible hoses - it's not unknown for these to collapse internally which allows fluid through under pressure to apply the brakes, but provides much more resistance to the return flow, causing the brake to stick.
To replace the pistons you'd need the facilities and skill to properly rebuild the caliper, checking that the bores are correct, replacing all the seals and bleed screws, etc - it's not a job for a beginner, and by the time you've done all that it'll probably cost more than just buying a pair of new or professionally refurbished calipers...
Also, I can't think of any scenario that'd cause enough damage to the pistons to need replacing, without also causing significant damage to the caliper casting, needing at least a rebore (which needs proper machine tools).
Basically, best to replace the whole thing. Don't cut corners with brakes!

hey Nick, thanks for this answer. but yeah to summarize, I think I might have to just get a new caliper to skip all the unnecessary troubleshooting.

Does the wheel spin freely with the caliper removed, without any rumbling, tight spots, etc? Yes, when the mechanic lifts the car, and spins the wheel, we don't notice any resistance at all. Is all the alignment correct? yup, done the alignment multiple times.
sliding pins are also new. and yeah, I was not the one that applied the repair kit, but the mechanic.
the caliper rebore, I haven't thought of that but I'll see if shops offer that service in our area

Don't forget to check the rubber brake hose before you slap money into it. Sometimes a damaged hose will not allow fluid back when releasing the brake pedal causing these symptoms.
